# Why does pyspark throws cannot run program "python3"?

Tags: pyspark

I started the cmd-shell from the anaconda environment. Then I entered`pyspark`. This loaded the interactive spark-shell.
Then I tried the following command:

```
l = [('Alice', 1)]
spark.createDataFrame(l).collect()
```

Which caused:

```
22/02/14 19:16:03 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 5.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 21)
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:453)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:140)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
        ... 30 more
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Run before SparkSession/SparkContext:

```
import os
import sys

os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
```

Comment: So, I guess this is because pyspark calls java which then calls python?